# Selecting a row from a table in react native and moving the selected row with its data to a table in another page?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

```js
 const SelectedRow=()=>{
    return navigation.navigate("CariHesapListesiDetayli",{selectedRow:response.Hareketler.filter(item=>item.Kodu===kod)} )
  }
```

```css
    <FlatList
        data={filteredData}
        numColumns={1}
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index + ''}
        ListHeaderComponent={tableHeader}
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return (
      
            <TouchableOpacity  style={{
                ...styles.tableRow,
                backgroundColor: index % 2 == 1 ? 'gray' : '#e5e5e5',
              }}
              onPress={SelectedRow}> 

              <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{index+1}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{item.Adi}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{item.Kodu}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.columnRowTxt}>{item.Bakiye}</Text>

            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
```

I want to import the data from the row I clicked into a table on another screen.
When I want to result other screen using console.log() gives me a "undefined" ...

Comment: Can you please also add in your question what's in your response, and also what you are logging in to the console?

Comment: @ebrua please check my answer and let me know what happened..!

Answer (score -1):

==> First let's simplify the code.

```
let tempResponse = response.Hareketler.filter(item=>item.Kodu===kod)
```

Store it on another variables and log the console.

if the result is getting then getting the value then pass into the navigation like this.

```
 const SelectedRow=()=>{
        return navigation.navigate("CariHesapListesiDetayli",{selectedRow:tempResponse} )
      }
```

==> and log that value in another screen, like this.

```
const {selectedRow} = route.params

console.log(">>>>",selectedRow)
```

Comment: {key: 'CariHesapListesiDetayli-9XsDnI65obfqbIzaemo9z', name: 'CariHesapListesiDetayli', path: undefined, params: undefined, Symbol(CHILD_STATE): undefined}
key
: 
"CariHesapListesiDetayli-9XsDnI65obfqbIzaemo9z"
name
: 
"CariHesapListesiDetayli"
params
: 
undefined
path
: 
undefined
Symbol(CHILD_STATE)
: 
undefined
[[Prototype]]
.

Comment: @ebrua so what's happen..?,you give exact output or not..?

Comment: It is no longer undefined but I still don't have access to the datas I want.

Comment: you are getting the right output in this log..? ```console.log(">>>", tempResponse)```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectedRow')
 It started giving this error even though I didn't make any changes